# Summarise a logical Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, summarize

I have a large matrix filled with True/False values under each column. Is there a way I can summarize the matrix so that every row is unique and I have a new column with the sum of how often that row appeared.

Example:

```
    A B C D E
[1] T F F T F
[2] T T T F F
[3] T F F T T
[4] T T T F F
[5] T F F T F
```

Would become:

```
    A B C D E total
[1] T F F T F  2
[2] T T T F F  2
[3] T F F T F  1
```

## EDIT

I cbind this matrix with a new column *rev* so I now have a data.frame that looks like

```
    A B C D E rev
[1] T F F T F  2
[2] T T T F F  3
[3] T F F T T  5
[4] T T T F F  2
[5] T F F T F  1
```

And would like a data.frame that also sums the rev column as follows:

```
    A B C D E rev total
[1] T F F T F  3    2
[2] T T T F F  5    2 
[3] T F F T T  5    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach with `dplyr` :

use `as.data.frame` (or here `as_tibble`) first if you start from a `matrix`. In the end you need to have a `data.frame` anyway as you'll have both `numeric` and `logical` in your table.

```r
mat <- matrix(
 c(T, F, F, T, F, T, T, T, F, F, T, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F, F, T, F, F, T, F),
 ncol = 5,
 byrow = TRUE,
 dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:5])
)

library(dplyr)
mat %>%
  as_tibble %>%    # convert matrix to tibble, to be able to group
  group_by_all %>% # group by every column so we can count by group of equal values
  tally %>%        # tally will add a count column and keep distinct grouped values
  ungroup          # ungroup the table to be clean
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   A     B     C     D     E         n
#>   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <int>
#> 1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE     2
#> 2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE      1
#> 3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE     2
```

Created on 2018-05-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

And a base solution:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
df$n <- 1
aggregate(n~.,df,sum)
#      A     B     C     D     E n
# 1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 2
# 2 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 2
# 3 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 1
```

Or as a one liner: `aggregate(n~.,data.frame(mat,n=1),sum)`

Comment: Are you able to break down what exactly is happening in the code? I haven't used the dplyr package before.

Comment: I added comments, to understand `%>%` the keywords are pipe, dplyr, and magrittr.

Comment: @Calum tally doesn't do anything different from count here

Comment: The base solution is what I'm going with. It easier for me to understand and I can apply the same line to different columns. Thank you.

Comment: The `[[<-` is a bit of overkill, you could just do `aggregate(n ~ ., data.frame(mat,n=1), FUN=sum)`

Comment: good point, edited

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yeah i know, it's just to reflect the intended use of `tally` vs `count`

Answer (score 2):

`count` function from `plyr` is exactly what you are looking for (suppose `m` is your matrix):

```
plyr::count(m)

#   x.A   x.B   x.C   x.D   x.E freq
#1 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    2
#2 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE    1
#3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object `mat` as defined in @Moody_Mudskipper's answer, you can do

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mat)

dt[, .N, by = names(dt)]

#       A     B     C     D     E N
# 1: TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 2
# 2: TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 2
# 3: TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 1
```

Explanation

`by = <names>` divides the data table into groups of rows, where the value of all the variables in `<names>` is equal across rows. If you do `by = names(dt)` it will divide into groups where all variables are equal.

`.N` is the number of observations in the given group of rows.

For your edit, if your data.frame is named `df`, you can do

```
setDT(df) # convert to data table
df[, .(rev = sum(rev), total = .N), by = A:E] # get desired output

#       A     B     C     D     E rev N
# 1: TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE   3 2
# 2: TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   5 2
# 3: TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE   5 1
```